# How to wrap a really long paragraph R output in R knitr

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave

I'm trying to put a long paragraph into a pdf file using R Sweave/Knitr. This long paragraph is extracted from one of the excel columns and pasted together. You can consider the paragraph as a 1 by 1 object:

```
cat("loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong")
```

Currently, if I complie this long paragraph into a pdf:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \begin{document}

 <<warning=FALSE, comment=NA, message=FALSE, echo=FALSE, tidy=TRUE,background="white">>=

 cat("looonno, oooooooooooooooooooooo, ooooooooooooooooooooooo, ooooooooooooooooooo, ooooonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnng")

 @

 \end{document}
```

the output cannot wrap the text itself and the result will always be like this:
[image]

The output is outside the edge of the page.

I have tried using `option(width=60)`, but it doesn't help in this situation unless there are multiple items in one object.

Hope some could come up with an idea that make the text wrap within the margin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With combination of `strwrap`, `writeLines` and appropriate `width` parameter you could do:

**Output:**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<warning=FALSE, comment=NA, message=FALSE, echo=FALSE, tidy=TRUE,background="white">>=



x=paste0("looonno, oooooooooooooooooooooo, ooooooooooooooooooooooo, ooooooooooooooooooo, ooooonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnng, texttttttttttttttttttttttttt,
        goessssssssssssssss,onnnnnnnnnnn, foreverrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr, annnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnd, everrrrrrrr")

cat("Before:","\n")

cat(x,"\n")

cat("After:","\n")

cat(writeLines(strwrap(x, width = 100)))


@

\end{document}
```